# Behavior of `git push --force` when no upstream branch exists

Tags: git, version-control

What's the behavior of `git push --force` when no upstream branch exists?

Will I get something like `fatal: The current branch branch_name has no upstream branch`, as would happen with a normal push, or would the upstream branch be "forcefully" created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--force` does not change the behaviour of `git push` without an upstream set (when no `push.default` and `push.autoSetupRemote` config is set) empirically with git 2.40.0.

```
$ git checkout -b dev/test
Switched to a new branch 'dev/test'
$ git push
fatal: The current branch dev/test has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin dev/test

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.

$ git push --force
fatal: The current branch dev/test has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin dev/test

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.
```